# Groupping Probability

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-theory

I have this scenario:

> 10 people with 100% of probability of dying in 1 month.

So I **probabily gonna have** at the end of the month:

10 dead people; 
0 alive people. 

I also have this scenario:

> 10 people with 60% of probability of dying in 1 month.

So I also **probabily gonna have** at the end of the month:

6 dead people;
4 alive people.

Is that correct?

I mean, the "probability" of dying is **per person**, not about the group. But can I assume this result in the end of the month **grouping people** with the same probability of dying?

When I say that the probability of dying is per person, I mean, in the second scenario I have:
*Person 1 with 60% of probability of dying; Person 2 with 60% of probability of dying; (...) Person 10 with 60% of probability of dying.*

So this "6 dead people and 4 alive people" is a information that I can get groupping people like I wrote?

Comment: I think I've seen this question before or at least one similar but I may be wrong. Have you tried searching the site?

Comment: @Karl, I asked a question similar to this. But I didn't get answer. So I rephrased it, studied about it and wrote it with a different approach.

Answer (score 1):

The word you want is "Expectation"; the mean value of results.

The count of fatalities among a population of $n$ people with (independent) fatality rate $p$ can be modeled as a **Binomial Distribution**, which has an **Expected Value** of $np$ and **Variance** of $np(1-p)$.

Comment: But Graham Kemp, I would like to consider the "probability about die". Is there any subject that could help me inside probability?

Comment: @FelipeM Yes, research the topic: **Binomial Distribution**.